# Axios get request using vue / vscode

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to make a get request using Axios and not sure where I am going wrong. In my IDE vscode terminal / console.log() it is showing the data being pulled in from the api correctly however in my browser I am getting a 400 error. Any idea what could cause this issue?

```html
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          apiUrl: 'api',
          name: '',
        };
      },
      created() {
        axios
          .get(`${apiUrl}`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: '****',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
          });
      },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What is the content of the data that is being logged? Also, if it is a public API then would you be able to add it to the code for error replication?

Comment: Does the query work with a Postman?

Comment: I tested query inn Blazemeter similar to postman and it is returning 200. It should be working fine but is not in local dev. throwing 400 error.

in the network tab previous / response are showing:

{
  "message": "Only supports Content-Type: application/json"
}

Comment: In the devtools, do you see the correct "content-type" header in the request? Try to grab the failing request in the Network tab, copy it to curl, and run it somewhere else (Blazemeter, postman, terminal) to see if it still fails.

Comment: I just tried using the fetch api instead of axios and it works!. I must have axios setup incorrectly

Comment: actually axios is working fine, I tried a public API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and its returning data perfectly